# How to achieve SplitView Functionality in Portrait mode in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I'm trying to implement SplitView functionality in my iOS application, it's working fine only in landscape mode in iPad devices.

If I launch or rotate the application from landscape to portrait mode splitView functionality is collapsing.

How to achieve SplitView functionality in iPhone(portrait and landscape) and iPad(Portrait mode) devices?

Please find my code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkl7X.png) below code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];    
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    ViewController *masterViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController"
bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
    masterViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;
    self.splitViewController = [[CustomSplitViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CustomSplitViewController"  bundle:nil];
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController];
    TabBarDetailController *secondVC = [[TabBarDetailController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TabBarDetailController"  bundle:nil];
    secondVC.tabBarItem.title = @"Second";
    ThirdViewController *thirdVC = [[ThirdViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController"  bundle:nil];
    thirdVC.tabBarItem.title = @"Third";    
    FourthViewController *fourthVC =  [[FourthViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController"  bundle:nil];
    fourthVC.tabBarItem.title = @"Fourth";    
    MoreViewController *moreVC =  [[MoreViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MoreViewController"  bundle:nil];
    moreVC.tabBarItem.title = @"More";

    //make an array containing view controllers
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.splitViewController,secondVC,thirdVC,fourthVC,moreVC,nil];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];    
    self.splitViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"HOME";
    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    self.window.rootViewController=tabBarController;
    [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];
     return YES;
 }
```

Thanks in advance.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at `.preferredDisplayMode`? [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller/1623170-preferreddisplaymode)

Comment: A `UISplitViewController` is based on size classes. Starting with iOS 14 (maybe 13 even) that means that an iPhone in portrait will *always* display what you set to be the compact  VC, and an iPhone in landscape will show either secondary (4 sizes) or compact (6 sizes). As for iPads? Discounting a true "split screen" - meaning multiple apps on the screen, it should *always* show the secondary VC no matter the orientation. I don't know why you are seeing something different on an iPad. My best guess is your "root" VC hierarchy, which looks like the tab bar is at the root.